# AVD process gets killed as soon as I end debugging

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, android-virtual-device

My Setup is:
Server: Asp.Net and SignalR-Server
App: SignalR-Client

My App uses "Invoke" to invoke a function on my Server which should return a MyObject-Object. But the response isn't arriving at my client and the app 'hangs' in the async void in which the Invoke is located.

As soon as I end the debugging of the app the whole 
AVD-Process gets killed with no error message shown in the Emulator or Visual Studio.

I think this happens of a Exception which is 'silently' thrown.

How could the AVD get killed with an Exception of my app?

Comment: Without any code showing what you  are doing it is impossible to say what is going on. It is odd that the AVD is getting killed (which I assume means the AD shuts down and the AVD window is closed? Or does the AVD just become non-responsive? ) Also "Async void" methods should be avoided except for event handlers. If there is an exception in an "async void" method (that is not an event handler) it will get swallowed by the runtime. See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/because-this-call-is-not-awaited-the-current-method-continues-to-run

Comment: @jgoldberger the emulator process keeps getting killed without any hint why this happens. I am using override functions like `OnResume` which is by design `void`...

Comment: Did you add the async keyword to the OnResume method, e.g. `protected override async void OnResume()`? And if so, are you then awaiting the call to the async method and wrapping it in a try/catch to make sure you catch any exceptions that may happen in the async method? IOW, please show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for many inconsistencies I needed to let Visual Studio clean the whole project.

I think it is an underlying process which does some caching of files or values and then the application itself cannot use the cached data as I changed the usage of this data.

This is really annoying because now I always let Visual Studio clean the code after each edit on the code. And with this procedure I am getting less 'error-less' errors which aren't real errors...

Thanks anyway :)